# Left joining on a table, gets multiple records, reduce these 2 one ordered by smallest value

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a query where I list out some records, I also join on another table which results on multiple rows returned with the same ID due to multiple rows in the joined table:

```
array:35 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 1754853
    "monthly_payment" => "145.50"
    "regular_payment" => null
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 3006256
    "monthly_payment" => "272.81"
    "regular_payment" => null
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "id" => 3006257
    "monthly_payment" => "818.44"
    "regular_payment" => "90.37"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "id" => 3006257
    "monthly_payment" => "818.44"
    "regular_payment" => "964.43"
  ]
```

As you can see `3006257` is in the array twice. I now need to manipulate this data using any of Laravel's features to reduce this to a single item but using the lowest `regular_payment`. What is the best way to do this?

I opted to do a left join and not an additional query as only wanted to do the single query.

**Query**

```php
$vehicles = (clone $this->vehicles)
    ->select('id', 'monthly_payment', 'cache.regular_payment'))
    ->leftJoin('cache', 'cache.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
    ->get();
```

I have attempted to do `DB::raw('MIN(cache.regular_payment) as regular_payment'))` however this just returns the single row.

Comment: Can you share your query please ?

Comment: @Ludo.C Added to bottom of post.

Comment: Group by id and then use the MIN value

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed That works much better, thanks! Update my answer unless you want to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

** Edit **

Based on John's suggestion this works perfect!

```sql
->select('id', DB::raw('if (cache.regular_payment, min(cache.regular_payment), monthly_payment) as regular_payment'))
```

---

Managed to do what I want with `reduce`, might not be the cleanest code so if someone knows how to reduce the amount of code or make it cleaner that would be appreciated.

```php
$vehicles = $vehicles->reduce(static function ($carry, $item) {
    /** @var $carry Collection */
    $monthly_payment = $item->getAttribute('monthly_payment');
    $id = $item->getAttribute('id');
    
    if ($regular = $item->getAttribute('regular_payment')) {
        if ($carry->has($id)) {
            $monthly_payment = $carry->get($id)['monthly_payment'];
            if ($regular < $carry->get($id)['monthly_payment']) {
                $monthly_payment = $regular;
            }
        }
        if (!$carry->has($id)) {
            $monthly_payment = $regular;
        }
    }
    return $carry->put($id, [
        'id' => $id,
        'monthly_payment' => $monthly_payment
    ]);
}, collect([]));
```